# Block access for public computers in Kohana 3.2

Tags: authentication, kohana

I am running CRM based on Kohana in small office. Information is very sensitive so I want users to login only from office and not from home or anywhere else. I could block access by IP but office uses ADSL modem with dynamic IPs. Is there any way I can block unwanted connections from outside of my office.

Thank you!

Comment: A case for SE Network Engineering?

Comment: Or perhaps Server Fault?

Comment: ^^ these. This should be a network layer concern, not an application concern.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to bother with firewall you could do something like this

```
$start_ip = ip2long("192.168.1.1");
$end_ip = ip2long("192.168.1.254");

$ip = ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
if ($ip <= $start_ip OR $ip >= $end_ip) {
    throw new Exception("No access for outsiders!");
}
```

though I would advise to do this properly on your firewall.